# how can I add one more field "company name" in odoo while signup?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view, odoo-website

I wanted to put an extra field in odoo while signup procedure. If admin has created multi company then user gets options to choose the company during sign up.

[Demo screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvOhL.png)

can anyone pls help me how can I achieve this Dropdown menu for company options in signup form?

```
<option t-esc="nb"/></t>
```

and

```
<select></select>
```

have no idea how it works.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the module you wish to modify, in your case I think this is the "web" module. If you don't know how to inherit modules, I recommend going through [Odoo's developer documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html).

Answer (score 0):

Inherit AuthSignupHome class in auth_signup module to fetch multi company data and inherit auth_signup.signup template to include qweb web design to for dropdow with multi company data: 
try below code:

Controller.py:

```
class AuthSignupHome(openerp.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main.AuthSignupHome):
    company_ids = request.env["res.company"].sudo().search([])
    print'company_ids',company_ids
    qcontext['multi_company'] = company_ids

    return request.render('auth_signup.signup', qcontext)
```

In xml:

```
<template id="inherit_fields" inherit_id="auth_signup.fields" name="Sign up">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='form-group field-login']" position="before">
            <div class="selection">
                <select>
                    <t t-foreach="multi_company" t-as="company">
                        <option><t t-esc="company.name"/></option>
                    </t>
                </select>
            </div>
        </xpath>
</template>
```

I think it will help you..